# How to place multiples of three divs into list items?

Tags: php

I have content that is being outputting in endless divs. I'd like to surround mutiples of three within a list item, like this:

```
<li>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
</li>
<li>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
</li>
```

I'm trying to achieve this with the following code, but it's not working for some reason - it simply surrounds each div in its own li:

```
$i = 1;
if($setting) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<div>My div</div>';
    if ($i % 3 == 0) { 
        echo '</li><li>'; 
        }
    $i++;
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: that's invalid html BTW

Comment: There is no loop in your code.  You must include the loop that I assume your code is contained within.

Answer (score 2):

Without your loop, hard to say what you're doing wrong.

But here's a solution.

```
$numOfDivs = 12;

for ($thisDiv=0; $thisDiv < $numOfDivs; $thisDiv++) {
    if ($thisDiv==0) echo '<li>';
    else if ($thisDiv%3==0) echo '</li><li>';
    echo '<div>My Div</div>';
    if ($thisDiv == $numOfDivs-1) echo '</li>';
}
```

Bear in mind this produces the desired output, but that the desired output is invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a loop, it just seems to be inside a function

Comment: @user In your post, you said:  `I'm trying to achieve this with the following code` - but you didn't write the code?  I'm confused.

Comment: The code is for a Wordpress widget written by someone else. I'm trying to modify it with my limited PHP knowledge.